# Google Charts: Maps - requesting API Key

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I have some doubts about Google Charts library when we talk about maps and GeoCharts. I was having this issue that maps stopped working when simply changed the name of the file and this error popped up in my browser console:

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

I searched over the web and found some questions here declaring that the maps service VIA GoogleCharts (visualization) didn't have limitations nor charges. BUT, I was able to resolve the problem above using a free JS Map API key as oriented here: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2292

It's a standard free key, so no charges, but there are limitations, right?
What about geocoding??

So, wrapping up all, considering Google Charts scope:
1) Is there a limitation or charge for Google Charts Maps & Geochart view?
2) Is there a limitation or change for geocoding data?

Thanks you for the clarification!